# How to hide a button immediately when location permission is denied in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application where I need to ask for the user's location permission and show a button to find the nearest clinic based on their current location. If the user denies the permission, I want the button to disappear immediately instead of waiting for the user to click it.

I'm currently using navigator.permissions.query to get the permission state and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get the user's current position. Here's my code:

```js
const handleFindNearestSite = () =>
  navigator?.permissions?.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(permission => {
    setFindNearestClinicButtonEnable(permission.state !== 'denied');
    setSiteId(permission.state !== 'allowed');

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const coords = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      const { closestSiteId } = calculateMapSiteList(sites, country, coords);

      setSiteId(closestSiteId);
    });
  });
```

However, the button only disappears when the user clicks it or refreshes the page.
What I need is when I click 'block' the button 'find the nearest clinic' hide.

[image: Example of the issue]

I'm also sharing how I use it in the component

```js
{findNearestClinicButtonEnable && (
     <Button
      onClick={handleFindNearestSite}
      size="small"
      variant="contained"
       >
         <MyLocation className={classes.findNearestIcon} />
            <FormattedMessage
             defaultMessage="Find nearest clinic"
             id="ClinicForm.FindNearestClinic"
          />
         </Button>
                )}
```

This is the solution I tried using the `useEffect` but didn't worked

```
const locationPermissions = async () => {
    const permission = await navigator?.permissions?.query({
      name: 'geolocation',
    });

    // Checking if the user has declined permission ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query
    setFindNearestClinicButtonEnable(permission.state !== 'denied');
    setSiteId(permission.state !== 'allowed');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    locationPermissions();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You need to check permission on component mount and set the button state based on response. Button click should just find the current position and find nearest clinic.

Comment: I tried but nothing happen I'll update my question with the solution I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigation.permissions.query and then handle your event depending on the case. more informations about the API: [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API)

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then((result) => {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition,positionDenied,geoSettings);
    } else if (result.state === 'denied') {
      report(result.state);
      geoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    result.addEventListener('change', () => {
      report(result.state);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a callback function to get error on the getLocation

```
const handleFindNearestSite = () =>
  navigator?.permissions?.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then(permission => {
    setFindNearestClinicButtonEnable(permission.state !== 'denied');
    setSiteId(permission.state !== 'allowed');

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      const coords = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      const { closestSiteId } = calculateMapSiteList(sites, country, coords);

      setSiteId(closestSiteId);
    });
  },(err)=>{
     console.log(err) // expected output {code: 1, message: 'User denied Geolocation'}
  });
```

You can check it through err message to check and hide button using useState